# React native xcodebuild archive failed with exit status 65 on Fastlane - RealmJS Pods

Tags: xcode, react-native, realm, fastlane, realm-js

I am trying to automate my react native app publish to app store by using fastlane. Archiving the app manually using xcode is successful. However when i use Fastlane, the build app step fails with exit status 65.

error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/RealmJS/RealmJS-xcframeworks-input-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'RealmJS' from project 'Pods')

error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/RealmJS/RealmJS-xcframeworks-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'RealmJS' from project 'Pods')

I have tried deleting my Pods folder, Podfile.lock and doing a fresh pod install. However, the issue with realmJS still occurs.

**XCode version:** Version 13.0 (13A233)

**React-native:** 0.65.1

**Realm-js:** 10.8.0

**Fastlane:** 2.197.0

[image: Fastlane error]

Anyone encountered similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work. Turns out I had specified the wrong configuration for the build_app step in the Fastfile. I had renamed my configuration from "Release" to "Release Staging" after creating different schemes.

So from:

```
build_app(
      configuration: "Release",
      export_method: "app-store",
...
)
```

To:

```
build_app(
      configuration: "Release Staging",
      export_method: "app-store",
...
)
```